# How many MCU villains were in some way created by the Stark family?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

A popular trend in the Marvel Cinematic Universe is that villains in the various films and TV shows are in some way created by Tony Stark, or in some cases his father Howard. In a literal sense, this includes the AI Ultron, but in a more metaphorical sense includes Whiplash and Aldrich Kilian. My question is: what MCU villains were the result of either of the Starks? This includes the cinematic and television versions. They could have been screwed over, literally created, or some other thing.

Comment: How many degrees of separation are you allowed for. For example, in Whiplash's case, Howard asked the US Government to deport his father, then Anton made claims to the Russian government he couldn't live up to, then Russians sent him to Siberia, then he became a drunk, and then did a terrible job raising his kid. There's four or five degrees there. How is it Stark's fault that Anton lied about his capabilities and the Russian government called him on it? Ivan's anger is misplaced; he's about revenge, not justice - he blames Howard Stark, but is it really Howard's fault?

Comment: @T.J.L. typical Stark apologist fanboy!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He he he... I'm not saying Stark isn't a galactic-class jerk, but *everything* isn't his fault. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. but Iron Man was the start, it's *all* his fault

Comment: Definitely thought this was about the Stark family from _Game of Thrones_ at first glance at the title and was _super_ confused...

Comment: Project: Rebirth originated the Super-Soldier program, so Starks get credited with the eventual creation of the Flag-smashers.

Comment: Also elevating Rumlow to Cross-bones is many degrees of separation traced to Stark who created Captain America, which became Rumlow’s mission to kill which failed badly and drove set him to go on as Crossbones.

Comment: Howard can be blamed again for Killmonger since he was the one that “discovered” vibranium, which profoundly impacted the vector of Wakanda and its ruling families.

Answer (score 22):

The Stark family were responsible for quite a lot of them.

### 1. Whiplash aka Ivan Vanko

Vanko's father was apparently [*kind of*] betrayed by Howard Stark that led to his death. Ivan thus made his life's goal to destroy the Starks.

> **Ivan**: What your father did to my family over 40 years, I will do to you in 40 minutes.
>    <sub>*Iron-Man 2 (2010)*</sub>

Also Fury clears up what happened between Howard Stark and Anton Vanko:

> **Fury**: Anton Vanko is the other side of that coin. Anton saw it as a way to get rich. When your father found out, he had him deported. When the Russians found out he couldn’t deliver they shipped his ass off to Siberia and he spent the next 20 years in a vodka-fuelled rage. Not quite the environment you want to raise a kid in, the son you had the misfortune of crossing paths with in Monaco.
>    <sub>*Iron-Man 2 (2010)*</sub>

---

### 2. Mysterio aka Quentin Beck

Tony took Beck's work and renamed it BARF, and also had him fired stating Beck to be *unstable*

> **Quentin Beck**: The jester king. Literally wrapped in wealth and technology that he was unfit to wield. Like the holographic system I designed. A revolutionary breakthrough with limitless applications that Tony turned into a self-therapy machine and renamed...
>
> [Brief flashback of Tony in Captain America: Civil War, where Tony Stark presents his final meeting with his parents, using the same holographic technology]
>
> **Tony Stark**: Binarily Augmented Retro-Framing, or BARF...
>
> [The crowd laughs while the hologram disappears and Tony takes off his glasses]
>
> **Tony Stark**: Oh, $611,000,000 for my little therapeutic experiment...?
>
> [Zoom in, Quentin Beck is standing behind Tony, with a disgusted grimace on his face]
>
> **Quentin Beck**: He renamed my life's work BARF. I told him that it was a mistake. That my technology can change the world. And then... He fired me. Said I was... unstable. 
>    <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home (2019)*</sub>

---

### 3. The Vulture aka Adrian Toomes

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Toomes tells Peter how Stark indirectly ruined his life:

> **Toomes**: (sighs) Peter, you’re young. You don’t understand how the world works.
>
> **Peter**: Yeah, but I understand that selling weapons to criminals is wrong.
>
> **Toomes**: How do you think your buddy Stark paid for that tower? Or any of his little toys? Those people, Pete, those people up there, the rich and the powerful, they do whatever they want. Guys like us, like you and me, they don’t care about us. We build their roads and we fight all their wars and everything, but they don’t care about us. We have to pick up after ‘em. We have to eat their table scraps. That’s how it is. I know you know what I’m talking about, Peter.
>
> **Peter**: Why are you telling me this?
>
> **Toomes**: Because I want you to understand.... 
>    <sub>*Spider-Man: Homecoming (2017)*</sub>

---

### 4. The Real Mandarin/Aldrich Killian

Flashback into the events before *Iron-Man (2008)*, in 1999, Bern, Switzerland's New Years Eve Party, the humiliation and ignorance led Killian to become Tony's archenemy.

---

**NOTE**: To name a few others,

- **Maximoff twins** were created and tortured by Hydra. Most importantly, their family was destroyed by bombings that used Stark weapons. However, the twins cannot be counted as villains, because they were simply misguided and misled.

  > **Pietro Maximoff**: We were ten years old, having dinner, the four of us. When the first shell hits, two floors below, it makes a hole in the floor. It's big. Our parents go in, and the whole building starts coming apart. I grab her, roll under the bed and the second shell hits. But, it doesn't go off. It just...sits there in the rubble, three feet from our faces. And on the side of the shell is painted one word...
  >
  > **Wanda Maximoff**: Stark.
- **Helmut Zemo** lost his family during *Avengers: AoU* thus made his goal to destroy the Avengers.
- **Iron Monger/Obadiah Stane**: His jealousy towards Tony

  > **Stane**: For 30 years, I've been holding you up! I built this company from nothing! Nothing is going to stand in my way.

---

### Some notable Stark villian creations (from the animated series)

1. [Swarm](https://thedailybugle.fandom.com/wiki/Swarm) (in *Ultimate Spider-Man Animated Series*)
2. [Ultron 5](https://avengersearthsmightiestheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Ultron-5) (in *Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes*)
3. [Yellowjacket](https://avengersearthsmightiestheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Yellowjacket_(episode)) (in *Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes*)
4. [Technovore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man:_Armored_Adventures) (in *Iron Man: Armored Adventures*)
5. [Alexander Nevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Dynamo#Alexander_Nevsky) aka Crimson Dynamo (in the comics)
6. [Valentin Shatalov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimson_Dynamo#Valentin_Shatalov) aka Crimson Dynamo (in the comics)
7. [Iron Skull and Cosmic Skull](https://avengersassemble.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Skull) (in *Avengers: Assemble*)

**PS**: The list is very long, I intend to add more names when I find them.

Comment: Howard Stark pissed off Hank Pym, so Hank left SHIELD and I guess therefore started working with Darren Cross, who as a result of _that_ became Yellowjacket. So that’s kind of an indirect one almost. (I guess further to that, Ghost in Ant-Man 2 possibly counts.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was talking about Yellowjacket from the animated series. Tony forces Hank to use lethal force while Hank doesn't want to. He quits the avengers, and the mental trauma creates a SPD, the Yellojacket.

Comment: But that's a good connection there. MCU's Yellowjacket and Ghost could be indirectly Starks' fault

Comment: Yellowjacket only does so because he felt betrayed by Hank. I think that, and certainly Ghost, are a bit too much of a stretch to be Stark’s fault.

Comment: @Shreedhar oh yeah I know, I was just seeing how far we could stretch it in the movies. I think The Deadly Vegetable is right, it’s a bit indirect to pin MCU Ant-Man villains on MCU Starks. But I think they’re both arguably Pym-created. Likewise Killmonger in _Black Panther_ is kinda T’Chaka’s fault, Loki and Malekith are pissed off by Odin, and Kaecillius (and possibly in the future Mordo) are basically down the the Ancient One in Doctor Strange. It’s almost as if there’s [one single person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Feige) influencing the plots of all these movies!

Comment: You're forgetting Ultron.

Comment: More tangentially - Howard Stark retrieved and studied the Tesseract (allowing the events of Avengers and Captain Marvel). He's also involved in a bunch of the Agent Carter events.

Comment: Howard also developed the Vita-Rays that were instrumental in the super-serum project. Attempts to recreate this project created Hulk, Abomination, and The Winter Soldier(s).

Comment: It's a stretch, but Captain Marvel's rescue of Stark in *Endgame* also inadvertently rescued Nebula as well, and it was Nebula's involvement in the Time Heist that alerted past-Nebula (and by extension past-Thanos) to their plans.  Thus, this version of Thanos was sort of accidentally indirectly created by Stark.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Arguably more "assisted" or "rescued" than "created" - Thanos already existed as a villain, Nebula just gave him the opportunity to bypass a terminal craniectomy courtesy of Thor

Comment: @Chronocidal Appropriate username for that topic.  On a more general level, Stark Industries has evidently been arming terrorist organizations in Afghanistan for years.  Some of that was on Obadiah Stane of course, but presumably not all of it.  Also, his busted up Mark I suit that he left in the desert was found and used by the same terrorists.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yeah thats what i was thinking. He directly created Ultron himself. Its clear that he should be in here too at the top no less.

Comment: Re: Item 4, "Flashback into the events before Iron-Man (2008), in 1999, Bern, Switzerland's New Years Eve Party...", where is this flashback from?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins iron man 3.

Comment: @Shreedhar: So you should add it to the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Mysterio, and the Vulture are both created by being screwed over by Tony Stark.  Zemo's family was killed by the events at Sokovia, Wanda and Quicksilver were 'tortured' by stark weaponry.